# How to filter out RDDs based on multiple conditions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

For illustrations purpose, I have a dataset with 3 columns `(X, Y, Z)`. Now, I want to calculate `Total z` or `Avg z` value for a year between 2001 and 2008.

To filter out year, I know:

```
ps2 = ps1.filter(lambda x: int(x[0])>2001 and int(x[0])<2008)
```

But how to create a new column with `total_z` or `avg_z` values for each year?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you just want the average value for every year, but if you do, use the simple aggregation:

```
 p2.groupby('X').avg('Z')
```

which give you a result:

```
+----+------+
|   X|avg(Z)|
+----+------+
|2003| 600.0|
|2002| 262.5|
+----+------+
```

If you need to keep `Y` column and duplicate the same average result like this:

```
+----+---+---+-----+
|   X|  Y|  Z|  avg|
+----+---+---+-----+
|2003| FL|600|600.0|
|2002| NY|300|262.5|
|2002| AZ|225|262.5|
+----+---+---+-----+
```

this code should help you:

```
    p2 = df.filter((df['X'] > 2001) & (df['X'] < 2008))
    partitioned = Window.partitionBy('X')
    result = p2.withColumn('avg', avg('Z').over(partitioned))
    result.show()
```

Comment: Raise AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'agg'

Comment: Could you convert RDD to DF or you strictly need RDD?